# GameObject' does not contain a definition for 'AddForce' || Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an error:

```
'GameObject' does not contain a definition for 'AddForce' and no accessible extension method
'AddForce' accepting a first argument of type 'GameObject' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Code:

```
public float power = 500.0f;
GameObject var;

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision myCollision) {
if (myCollision.gameObject.name == "Cube") {
    var = GameObject.Find("Cube");
    var.AddForce(new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, power));
  }
}
```

I want change coords of current object, in a collision with other objects.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From what you are trying to, I am assuming that you are trying to add a force to the object that it has collided with.

First of all, you did:

```
if (myCollision.gameObject.name == "Cube")
  {
    var = GameObject.Find("Cube");
    var.AddForce(new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, power));
  }
```

Try to avoid `GameObject.Find(string)` method, as it is an expensive call.
In fact, you don't even need to do that, since you actually have the game object you are colliding with already, that is what the `myCollision` for.

You can do this instead:

```
if (myCollision.gameObject.name == "Cube")
  {
    var = myCollision.gameObject; // Aka the gameobject you have collided with.
    var.AddForce(new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, power));
  }
```

**Going back to the question**, what you were trying to do is to add force to a rigidbody, but however `var` is of type `GameObject`, not `RigidBody`.

What you need to do is to get the component of the `RigidBody` from the `GameObject`, like so:

```
var.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(...
```

Note that a null reference exception occurs if the GameObject does not have a Rigidbody component attached to it.
Make sure the cube you are colliding with has a RigidBody component in the Unity's Inspector.

Also, you might want to note that repeated `GetComponent()` calls can be expensive. You can consider caching it if possible.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have next string: Cube.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, power));  
By collision in console i have next error: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Cube have rigidbody. All code: https://pastebin.com/bR9wuu9H

Comment: @bass_devware Notice that you never assigned `Cube`; Do a `Cube = myCollision.gameObject;` before adding force. (Or you can replace `Cube` with `myCollision.gameObject`)